# error CS0426 : The type name 'Create' does not exist in the type 'WebRequest'

Tags: c#, wcf

Using VS 2015: Please tell my why the System.Net.WebRequest object fails with error CS0426 on the following calls:

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest wr = new System.Net.WebRequest.Create(@"http://") as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
```

and

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest wr = new System.Net.WebRequest.CreateHttp(@"http://") as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
```

I have reference:

```
System.Net
System.Net.Http
System.Net.Http.WebRequest
```

I have installed:
Windows and Web Development : 
 Microsoft Web Developer Tools

And have successfully compiled and run a WCF WebHttpBinding sevice using the same installation on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot use the 'new' keyword in this context. (Sorry I must be convoluted with C++, C++/CLI, C# syntax, I lost it)